# Как правильно писать: "согласно техпроцесса" или "согласно техпроцессу"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

Как правильно писать: *согласно техпроцесса* или *согласно техпроцессу*?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: "техпроцессу". *Согласно* требует дательного падежа: *согласно чему?*.

Родительный падеж (согласно чего?) сильно устарел, может использоваться только для стилизации речи чиновников времен Пушкина.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: согласно техпроцессу ( дат.пад.).

**Грамота.ру**

Как правильно: согласно приказа, договора, распоряжения или согласно приказу, договору, распоряжению?

Правильно: согласно приказу, договору, распоряжению, штатному расписанию и т. д.

Предлог согласно в современном русском языке требует дательного падежа, правильно: согласно чему, не чего. Уже в XIX веке конструкция согласно чего, то есть с родительным падежом, расценивалась как характерная примета официально-деловой, канцелярской речи. А в современном русском языке она не является нормативной и для официально-делового стиля. Сейчас правильно только: согласно чему, то есть с дательным падежом.

Comment: А при чем тут "Грамота" в конце концов?! Авторитетность источника упала ниже всякой критики, а вы рассматриваете как самодостаточную догму.

Comment: Я не понимаю, о чем вы говорите, но если я взял с Грамоты, должен же я указать источник.

Comment: Я говорю о том, что механическое копирование ответов с любого источника - не самое благодарное занятие. Умением пользоваться гуглом сейчас мало кого удивишь. Здесь ценится умение объяснить, дать возможность спрашивающему разобраться, а не зазубрить тиражируемое с источника на источник заклинание.

Comment: А что касается "Грамоты" - источник давно перестал быть авторитетным. Я не против, чтобы на неё ссылались, но не как на самодостаточную истину в последней инстанции.